# Redirect outputs of multiple commands to a file

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, syntax, output

I'm running multiple commands in my Linux shell at the same time, e.g.

```
echo "Line of text 1" && echo "Line of text 2" && complexthing | xargs printf "complexspecifier"
```

I want to redirect all output to `file1`. I know I can add `>file1` after each individual command but this seems bulky. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
exec >file1   # redirect all output to file1
echo "Line of text1"
echo "Line of text2"
exec > /dev/tty  # direct output back to the terminal
```

Or, if you are on a machine that doesn't have `/dev/tty`, you can do:

```
exec 5>&1 > file1  # copy current output and redirect output to file1 
echo foo
echo bar
exec 1>&5 5>&-  # restore original output and close the copy
```

Comment: For the relative noobs: what is `5` in this example? Why `5` and not `6` or `4`? Having a link to documentation would also be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Leonid There is no reason to choose 5 instead of 6 or 4.  As long as you choose a file descriptor that is not already in use.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need to run your commands in a subshell, you could use `{ ... } > file`:

```
{ echo "Line of text 1" && echo "Line of text 2" && complexthing | xargs printf "complexspecifier"; } > file1
```

Note that you need a space after `{` and a semicolon before `}`, unless you have an `&` or a newline after the last command.

Comment: Just a note of explanation... this is basically a *"compound statement"* in the current shell, as opposed to a new sub-shell or process.

Comment: Note the `;` before the closing brace. Important not to forget it, for example when piping 2 commands  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. You can use parenthesis around the commands, then append `>file1`:

```
(echo "Line of text 1" && echo "Line of text 2" && complexthing | xargs printf "complexspecifier") >file1
```

Comment: Piping anything into `printf` is futile as it doesn't read from its stdin.

Comment: @codeforester My bad, I meant `xargs printf`. Fixed.

Comment: The parentheses cause the commands to run in a separate subshell, which may or may not be useful and necessary. You should probably understand the difference between `{ ...; }` and `( ... )` and then make an informed choice about which one to use.